# Ionic 3 Android build error

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3. Right now I'm trying to do `ionic cordova build android` , but I get **TypeError: env.runcmd is not a function** (please see the photo attached).

[image: the screenshot]

I tried to:

-> `ionic cordova platform rm android` then `ionic cordova platform add android` then again build android again

-> delete `node_modules` folder and do `npm install` then build android again

But none of them helped it...

My `ionic info` output:
[image]

Comment: Add output of `ionic info`.

Comment: Try to update/reinstall npm,angular,cordova, ionic etc and try again.

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa Just did edit post

Comment: Try with `npm install -g cordova@6.5.0`

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa Didn't help it.. `cordova -v` outputs now 7.0.1

Comment: Did you downgrade Cordova to 6.5.0

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa Oh, I did not. I guess `-g` means to install it globally, right? Should I put sudo at the beginning of the command?

Comment: Yes with sudo and try building apk.

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa For some reason, `sudo npm install -g cordova@6.5.0` doesn't downgrade it. `cordova -v` still outputs `7.0.1`

Comment: Uninstall 7 first then install 6.5

Comment: @SwapnilPatwa Just tried to re-install it, still outputs `7.0.1` :| Any ideas?

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12561

Comment: I am not familiar in linux. Find the "AppData" directory or relevant directory in linux and remove the "cordova" and "cordova-cli" directories from "npm\node_modules" and reinstall the cordova. In windows to fix this, Remove the "cordova" and "cordova-cli" directory from "AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules" and reinstall the cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, guys, the problem was exactly with cordova version. I haven't noticed when it did update to the version `7.0.1`. However, I had to downgrade it to version `6.5.0` and then android build succeeded.

The only thing that confused me was the downgrade process. Every time I did `sudo npm uninstall cordova -g`, the `cordova` command was still available at bash. If I would do `sudo npm install cordova@6.5.0 -g`, the version still remained `7.0.1`. Even some other commands such as `... --save --save-exact ...` did NOT work.

So below are the steps which I've gone through to solve this issue (I am using Ubuntu linux, so *this will work for linux users only*).

First I uninstalled cordova through npm
`sudo npm uninstall cordova -g`

Then removed the program from local bin
`sudo rm /usr/local/bin/cordova`

Installed the specific version of cordova
`sudo npm install cordova@6.5.0 -g` (or whatever version you want)

And lastly, I have to admit that after cordova installation, it was now located at `/usr/bin/cordova`, no more at `/usr/local/bin/cordova`, so I had to create a hard link to it.
`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/cordova /usr/bin/cordova`

Voilà!

Answer (score 1):

Just use command 'cordova run android'  instead of 'ionic cordova run android'.